# Getting non-localized description or key from NSError

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, nserror

Is there any way to get non-localized key or description from the `NSError`? I need some way to group errors from API requests and send them back for analytics, but it seems all descriptions or keys that we can get from the `NSError` are the localized ones.

I have tried the following:

- getting `error.code : error.domain` - which is not very helpful since the domain is mostly the same
- getting `error.userInfo[NSDebugDescriptionErrorKey] : error.userInfo[NSURLErrorKey]` - both of them are `nil`, so not very helpful either

At this point I do not think it is possible to do it, but would love to hear other thoughts as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155497/how-to-always-get-english-string-from-nserror ?

Comment: For analytics shouldn't the `code` and `domain` properties be enough?